# Kafka - understand when all consumers performed seek to LATEST

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have multiple consumers in a consumer group (single Spring Boot app). I use `onPartitionsAssigned` callback to reset every consumer offset to LATEST (for assigned partitions).

The issue is that I need to know when ALL consumers in a consumer group performed this seek and do some logic AFTER that.

My current understanding is that every consumer performs seek and start processing independently  - i.e. there is no any common synchronization point.

It would be great is someone can provide guidance whether this is possible at all.

UPDATE. Let me explain why is it needed.
I have a logic to send HTTP request (to another service) to request some data to be submitted to Kafka. But before sending this request I need to make sure that all consumers are at the latest offset already. Because if this request is sent earlier - some data submitted by this 2nd service may be lost - i.e. if it's submitted before a consumer completed reset to LATEST offset.

Comment: Do you just need to know when your consumers are at the latest ? And then do manual action? Or you are looking to do it on programming?

Comment: Correct . yes - on programming.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in; you could use a CountDownLatch set to the concurrency of the container and count it down for each one.

If the concurrency might change, you can get a reference to the concurrent container from the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean.

```
int count = ((ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>) registry.getListenerContainer(id))
    .getConcurrency();
```

Comment: At which point can I plug this CountDownLatch in?. Looking at spring-kafka code I don't see any place where it allows to specify sort of callback to understand when a consumer has successfully sought to specified offset (in my case the LATEST).

Comment: As I said, there is nothing built in for this. You would need to put the latch in some utility class and call `await(....)` in your listeners and `countDown()` in the `onPartitionsAssigned()` (only once per thread).

Comment: The issue that `callback.seekToEnd` is not synchronous - the request to reset offset is sent asynchronously. So we can't call `countDown` right after this method.

Comment: Why do you say that? The callback immediately performs the seek on the consumer. If you are seeing something different, edit the question to show your code.

Comment: No it's not - it just sets FetchState,AWAIT_RESET and resetStrategy. An actual request to get latest offset is executed later. This is not my code - it's spring-kafka/kafka code.

Comment: Yes, but the `onPartitionsAssigned()` is called by the `poll()` and before any records are returned. Trust me; it will only fetch records after the seek.

Comment: I updated the question to explain the issue in more details.

Comment: If you don't trust the behavior (but I don't understand why not), you could set the `idleEventInterval` and wait for each thread to publish one; use an `ApplicationListener<ListenerContainerIdleEvent>` (or an `@EventListener` method) to receive the events.